# Trying to use C++ Peek to get a line of code from a file

Tags: c++, file, peek

I'm trying to only get one specific line from a file using peek, then place values from that line into data type things.

```
for(int i = 0; i < students.length(); i++)
{
    int q = 0;
    fin >> name;
    students[i].n = name;
    while(fin.peek() != '\n')
    {
        students[i].tests.resize(students[i].tests.length()+1);
        fin >> test;
        students[i].tests[q] = test;
        q++;
    }
```

Peek was never really explained to me, how would I change this so that it would effectively resize students[i].tests to however many numbers I have in a specific line of the file? At this point it seems to be resizing infinitely.

Comment: Ummm have you read what does [`peek`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek) do? You probably don't want to use it for reading line. Even if you did, it's pretty impossible. You most probably need to change the whole code to use [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline). If you don't get it, I can elaborate in an answer why you can't peek a line, but the approach will need to be changed anyways, so I dunno if it would have any worth.

Comment: Each of the lines has a string in the form of a name and then a varying number of numbers corresponding to test scores, how would I use getline to assign values to a struct I've created that has one string for the name and a resizable vector of ints for the test scores?

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't work if there's whitespace before the newline, and will loop indefinitely when it hits end-of-file.

It's better practice to use a `std::istringstream` to parse out the numbers, and `push_back` them onto the `tests` `vector`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < students.length(); ++i)
{
    ASSERT_THROW(fin >> students[i].n, "unable to read student name");
    std::string line;
    ASSERT_THROW(getline(fin, line), "unexpected failure or EOF in file");
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    int n;
    while (iss >> n)
        students[i].tests.push_back(n);
    ASSERT_THROW(iss.eof(), "invalid content in '" << line
                 << "' after test scores");
}
```

Where `ASSERT_THROW` executes the code while checking for and throwing errors, e.g.

```
#define ASSERT_THROW(X, MSG) \
    do { \
        if (X) break; \
        std::ostringstream oss; \
        oss << __FILE__ << ':' << __LINE__ << " ASSERT_THROW(" \
              << #X << ") " << MSG; \
        throw std::runtime_error(oss.str()); \
    } while (false)
```